# read a file that contain ascii code greater than 128,the result is error

Tags: typescript, ionic2, blob, binaryfiles

I need to read a binary file  named "a.bin"  byte by byte,that stored in /src/assets directory(I write an App using ionic2 ,and I need to read some data from the directory),I tried some method as below,but if the file "a.bin" contains ascii code greater than 128,I find I get more bytes than the file contained,and the value is not the same as the file contains.
below is the source code :

```
public getFile()
  {
    this.getFileDataArray("a.bin").then((arr_buf)=>
    {
      console.log("the blob size is:"+arr_buf.size);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function ()
      {
        let blob=new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        for (let a=0;a<blob.byteLength;a++)
        console.log("---------no:"+a+"--value:"+blob[a]);
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(arr_buf);
    }
  }

  public getFileDataArray(filename:string):Promise<Blob>
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      this.http.get('assets/'+filename)
      .subscribe(res =>
        {
          resolve(new Blob([res['_body']],{type: "application/octet-stream" }));
        });
    });
  }
```

this is the origin content of the a.bin

[image]

but when I read the 34th byte,the result begin error,I think the app change the byte to a unicode. How can I get the correct result?
by the way,even change the getFileDataArray to the below(return Promise or Promise),I still cannot get the right result.

```
  public getFileDataArray(filename:string):Promise<text>
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      this.http.get('assets/'+filename)
      .subscribe(res =>
        {
          resolve(res.text());
        });
    });
  }
```

---------Promise---is still not correct-----------------
I

Comment: Is this thing Angular code? If so, which version of Angular?

Comment: @Vibha Pandey,Hi I used your method to read a file in src/assets,but my file is a binary file that contain some ascii code greater than 128,when i read the file ,I cannot read the content of the file correctly. as the question that i asked.

Comment: @kshetline,I used ionic2.and below is the info: @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

Comment: If the data is not text, don't treat it as such. If it is text, find out which character encoding (for example, UTF-8) was used to write it and decode it with that. Don't assume that a character encoding emits one byte for every character.

Comment: "ascii code greater than 128" isn't the real problem - there are lots of zeroes , this isn't text.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a character encoding issue here, but since I'm not sure which version of Angular comes along with "ionic-angular 3.9.2", so I don't know if this matches the `http` client you're using. It's at least worth a try:

```
this.http.get('assets/' + filename, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
```

Comment: type “{ responseType: "arraybuffer"; }”parameter cannot assigned to type“RequestOptionsArgs" 's parameter.@kshetline

Answer (score 0):

after some times ,I get an answer!

```
  public getFileData(filename:string):Observable<Blob>
  {
    return this.http.get('assets/'+filename, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
    .map(response => (response).blob());
  }
```